# Is there a multiplayer Chess GUI that allows you to choose the starting position?

Tags: software

With a human vs. computer, simply set Stockfish to `depth == 1` and play it. Or, you can choose another (weaker) engine.

With a human vs. human *online*, is it possible to set the starting position? If so, what is the website?

Comment: If you are looking for a certain opening to play, there are some websites which host e.g. themed tournaments from time to time. If you are talking about playing a specific position of your choice against a specific opponent, I have never seen that anywhere before (Chess.com, lichess, ICC, PlayChess).

Comment: @TMM Which websites, and what do you mean by _themes_?

Comment: I mean "themed tournaments" where the starting position is some opening variation. I've seen such tournaments on lichess (live) and on Chess.com (correspondence). I think on lichess such tournaments can be created by users, so probably users can choose the starting position, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play it in https://lichess.org/editor.
Chose your default opening, or just customize it, then click in 'Continue from here'.
You can chose if you want to play with with engine or with a friend.